# Click on element hightlight it and make other less visible

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

I'm with the following problem. I have block containing several divs that represent a product. The idea is that when the user clicks on one of the products, the product (div) is highlighted and the rest is less sharp. So far I was able to work this out, but when the user clicks on a second product, everything is less sharp included the new clicked one.

This is my jQuery code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $all_listItems = $('.choose-format-block .format-area a');
  $all_listItems.on('click', function () {
    var index = $all_listItems.index(this);
    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.6);
    $(this).parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.3);
  });

});
```

And this my working example with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/P7b5T/2/

Hopefully someone can help me out with this (am a beginner with jQuery).

Comment: Here is another way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/P7b5T/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible doing this with jQuery animations, I'd suggest to do this with CSS opacity and CSS transitions. Check out the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P7b5T/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $all_listItems = $('.choose-format-block .format-area a');
    $all_listItems.on('click', function () {
        $('.container').addClass('selected');
        $('.format-area.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('.format-area').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container .format-area {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.container.selected .format-area {
    opacity: .3;
}

.container.selected .format-area.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

First the container gets the class "selected", meaning that an item is selected. This sets all items opacity to .3. Then you give the selected item the class active to set the opacity back to 1.

EDIT: And when you want to go back to no selected items at all, just remove the class selected from the container.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not resetting the already `fadeout` div.

Do something like bellow. On each click first `reset` all the items after that `fadeTo` all others except clicked one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//product size on click behaviour
    var $all_listItems = $('.choose-format-block .format-area a');
    $all_listItems.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().children().stop().fadeTo(300, 1); //reset all Items
        $(this).parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.3); // fadeout others
    });

});
```